# Is it wrong to use , startservice every on create meythod on my app?

Tags: android, android-service

I have a service in my app. And I use `startservice` method on oncreate method so it works every running of my app , is it wrong way to do it?
if it is how can I manage it? should I control it and if it is not start then I start the service ? this is the right way?

thanks in advance

Comment: StartService() as it says start a service. you only do that when you want to process some work in background but don't want to interact with it often. Else you should bind your service and then start it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a service that should run in background all the time.

There are a few things you can do.

First lets start with an utility method which checks if server is running. Although it is considered as antipattern to use singleton, it is working good for this case

```
public static void startYourServiceIfNotRunning(Context context) {
    if(YourService.getRunningInstance() == null)
        context.startService(new Intent(context, YourService.class));
}
```

Also you should define your service as sticky inside your service class

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
    // stopped, so return sticky.
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

And also you can define a broadcast reciever like

```
public class BootCompletedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
    Util.startYourServiceIfNotRunning(context);
}
```

}

And xml code for the reciever, add to your manifest

```
 <receiver android:name="com.yourapp.BootCompletedReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" >
            </action>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" >
            </category>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And as the last thing, I call startYourServiceIfNotRunning() method in my main launcher activity. I do not call it anywhere else. And service is up all the time.

Hope this helps.

Hadi kolay gelsin :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you already looked at http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html ?
If you need a service that is running in the background then yes, startService is the correct way. You don't control it but the service manages itself so if it is not needed anymore it should stop itself.
If you just need the service on demand then another way is to bind and unbind to the service then it is controlled by the system. It really depends on your use case.

Comment: is it true every starts of app use startservice method? should I check if service stop then I can use startservice method?

Comment: What you usually do is to start your service at a central point i.e. create your own application class and then start the service from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look to the life cycle of service -  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ProcessLifecycle

I would suggest to use IntentService, as it is designed for handling asyncron tasks, it also start in a worker thread.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html

To really make this useful you have to define it in proper way.

Comment: is it true every starts of app use startservice method? should I check if service stop then I can use startservice method? or it does not matter ,

Comment: There is a quote from hackbod regarding service - "If your client and server code is part of the same .apk and you are binding to the service with a concrete Intent (one that specifies the exact service class), then you can simply have your service set a global variable when it is running that your client can check.

We deliberately don't have an API to check whether a service is running because, nearly without fail, when you want to do something like that you end up with race conditions in your code."